# Page object Model Is-A or Has-A?

Tags: selenium, inheritance, webdriver, composition, pageobjects

I am writing an Automation framework for a simple application and I have one question for few pages, should I use the inheritance or should I use the composition. And I would love to discuss that with you.

1.I have an abstract page which every page has to inherit. Now this page has so many wait method which I want to put outside of Page. Should I use inheritance for this. I mean Should I create a wait class and inherit that in Page class or should I use composition.
    public class waitTool {
        //All the wait methods
    }

```
public abstract class Page waitTool{
    //In case of this waitTool is abstract
}
I
public abstract class Page {
    protected WaitTool waitTool;
}

public class LoginPage extends Page {
}
```

2.Application has a menu bar which is common across all the pages. Should I create a separate Page for Menu bar and then inherit that in Page? Here, please think I might need to inherit waitTool class from above as well. or should I create this menuBar as navigate class. What I mean to say is, This class contains function to generate PageObject of each and every Page.

```
public class TopMenu extends Page{

    By homeLink = By.cssSelector("a[ui-sref='home']");

    public TopMenu(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }


    public void gotoHomePage(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have so many wait methods? What are some examples of the wait methods? Are they related to things on the page or generic wait methods? Anything to do with a given page should be in that page class. For the menu bar, a different class makes sense for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, make a class `Page` which only contains a constructor which initializes the page objects.

   ```
   public class Page
   {      
       public Page()
       {
           PageFactory.InitElements(SeleniumInfo.Driver, this);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make a class `SeleniumInfo` where you put the `static WebDriver` :

   ```
        public static class SeleniumInfo
        {
            public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
        }
   ```
3. Make an class `SeleniumExtensionMethods` that contain the extension methods. This will include your `wait` methods.

   ```
       public static class SeleniumExtensionMethods
       {
          public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumInfo.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            public static void SafeClick(this IWebElement webElement)
            {
             try
             {
               wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(webElement)).Click();
             }
             catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
             }

          }
       }
   ```
4. Any new page that you want to make a class for should inherit from the `Page` class created above. Here go your `IWebElements`. Like this:

   ```
       public class Page_Home : Page
       {

         [FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "Dashboard")]
         private IWebElement btnDashboard { get; set; }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Extend a base class only if the derived class has the 'IS A' relationship. If the page 'HAS A' component, then use composition!

I would suggest you to go with [Page Fragments](http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/) concepts.

[image]

You can take a look at the Arquillian lib for their [fluent wait API](http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-google-voice-search-automation-using-arquillian-graphene/). It is extremely easy to use!